# How to pronounce X-mas

Tags: pronunciation, abbreviations

How should I pronounce *Xmas*?

Is it the same as we pronounce the word *Christmas*?

Comment: Depends whether you want to emphasize the religious aspect or not. Despite the [answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/236631/63230) by choster, the X can be seen as replacing Christ with a free variable that can take any value, or none. As shown by the way many people celebrate Xmas. So I pronounce it ex-mus.

Comment: Pronounce it however you like.

Answer (score 3):

*Xmas* is an [abbreviation of ancient origin](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=Xmas) for *Christmas*, the Greek letter chi (*Χ*) being the initial letter of *Christ* (*Χριστός*), and the same in appearance if not pronunciation to the English letter *X*. As it is neither an acronym nor an initialism, I would ordinarily expect this abbreviation to be pronounced in full, just as I would expect to hear *Lt. Col. Jones* to be read as *Lieutenant Colonel Jones*, *Los Angeles, Calif.* as *Los Angeles, California*, or *Ss. Cyril and Methodius* as *Saints Cyril and Methodius*.

That said, [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/Xmas), [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/xmas), and [AHD](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=Xmas) among others all indicate both /ˈkrɪsməs/ and /ˈɛksməs/ as acceptable pronunciations. Certainly, those who wish to underscore the use of the abbreviation may choose to pronounce it as the latter.

The animated sitcom *Futurama* poked fun at the perennial panic (in the U.S., anyway) over forgetting the "true meaning of Christmas" by depicting a future in which Christmas has indeed been forgotten and replaced with a night of terror called [Xmas](http://futurama.wikia.com/wiki/Xmas) (/ˈɛksməs/).

Comment: *Great* Futurama link!

Answer (score 0):

/ˈkrɪs.məs//ˈeks.məs/ http://dictionary.cambridge.org/pronunciation/british/xmas will give you the pronunciation.

Wikipedia will give you the facts related to it.